# Loopback 4: Debug SQL Statements

Tags: loopback, loopback4

I'm new to Loopback. I have used Sequelize ORM in the past, and I'm used to seeing Sequelize output the SQL statements to the Console. How can I do the same with Loopback 4? I've done extensive searching on the web, and I found a place where they suggested to add `debug: true` to the datasource config json file. However, this change had no effect.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

We use [debug](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/4356) module to deal with debug logging and most connectors print SQL statements in their debug log.

You can enable debug logs by setting the environment variable `DEBUG`. For example, on a Unix system (Unix, MacOS), you can run the following command:

```
DEBUG=loopback:connector* npm start
```

On Windows, you have to set the variable in a standalone command.

```
set DEBUG=loopback:connector*
npm start
```

Comment: I'm using Windows. I did as you suggested. After I execute the two statements you suggested, I still don't see the SQL statement in the console. Should I be looking for the debug output somewhere else?

Comment: That's weird. Debug statements are printed to standard error output, you should see them in the console. Do you see at least _some_ debug statements? Also, what connector are you using?

Comment: I'm using loopback:connector:mssql connector. I built my app using lb4 app and I then started adding datasource, models, repositories, and controllers. And now I would like to see the SQL statements that are generated by lb.

Comment: On Windows, you can also use the system environment variables